# Parsing several structures with boost spirit

Tags: c++, data-structures, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I have to parse a netlist which looks like this:

```
*comment line 1
V1 N001 N002 10
R1 N001 N002 24.9

*comment line 2
R2 N002 N003 20
V2 N002 N003 5
```

This is how my structure looks like:
(The comment lines need to be in a separate structure in case this part needs to be expanded later)

```
  struct CommentLine {
  boost::optional<std::string> comment_line;
};

struct ElementStatement {
  boost::optional<std::string> label;
  boost::optional<std::string> node1;
  boost::optional<std::string> node2;
  boost::optional<double> value;
};

struct SpiceNetlist {
  std::vector<CommentLine> comment_lines;
  std::vector<ElementStatement> elements;
};
```

This is what I come up with using code suggested from a previous question:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(SpiceNetlist, comment_lines, elements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(CommentLine, comment_line)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ElementStatement, element_label, element_node1, element_node2, element_value)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It>
class SpiceGrammar : public qi::grammar<It, SpiceNetlist()> {
 public:
SpiceGrammar() : SpiceGrammar::base_type(spice_netlist_) {
     spice_netlist = qi::skip(qi::blank)[comment_lines >> (statements || comment_lines)];

    comment_lines = comment_line % qi::eol;
    comment_line = qi::lit('*') >> *(qi::graph) >> qi::space >> *(qi::graph) >>
               qi::space >> qi::graph;

    statements_    = statement_ % qi::eol;
    statement_     = -label_ >> -node1_ >> -node2_ >> -value_;
    label_         = qi::graph >> qi::graph;
    node1_         = qi::graph >> qi::graph >> qi::graph >> qi::graph;
    node2_         = qi::graph >> qi::graph >> qi::graph >> qi::graph;
    value_         = qi::double_;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((spice_netlist_)(comment_lines)(comment_line)(statements)    (statement)(label)(node1)(node2)(value))
  }

private:
qi::rule<It, SpiceNetlist()> spice_netlist_;

using Skipper = qi::blank_type;

Skipper skipper_;

qi::rule<It, std::vector<CommentLine>, Skipper> comment_lines;
qi::rule<It, std::string()> comment_line;
qi::rule<It, ElementStatements(), Skipper> statements_;
qi::rule<It, ElementStatement(), Skipper>  statement_;

qi::rule<It, std::string()> label_, node1_, node2_;
qi::rule<It, double()>      value_;
};

  
SpiceNetlist parse_netlist_from_string(std::string_view input) {
using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
static SpiceGrammar<It> const g;

SpiceNetlist netlist;

It f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
bool success = qi::parse(f, l, g, netlist);

std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted(input) << " -> "
          << "Parse " << (success ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED") << "\n"
          << "Remaining: " << quoted(std::string_view(f, l)) << std::endl;

return netlist;
}



   int main(){
    for (const auto &[comment] : netlist.comment_lines) {
          std::cout << "Comment: " << comment << std::endl;
        }
    for (auto const& [label, node1, node2, value] : netlist.elements) {
        std::cout                                                                              
            << "Element Label: " << label.value_or("Not specified") << "\n"                    
            << "        Node1: " << node1.value_or("Not specified") << "\n"                    
            << "        Node2: " << node2.value_or("Not specified") << "\n"                    
            << "        Value: " << (value ? std::to_string(*value) : "Not specified") << "\n" 
            << std::endl;
    }
    }
```

The parsing is successful until the second '*comment li' and the attributes are also being wrongly filled.
Is the problem with my grammar for spice_netlist or comment_line or am I defining the rule with the Skipper wrong?
I have also tried      spice_netlist = qi::skip(qi::blank)[comment_lines >> *(statements | comment_lines)]; but it generates build errors

Comment: In case it saves you time, there were *many* more code errors which I think I managed to fix already https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10bb848fae616f25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is how my structure looks like: (The comment lines need to be in a separate structure in case this part needs to be expanded later)

The structure doesn't match the input example. It loses the grouping of comment-lines with elementstatements.

Secondly, it really looks like you don't know what skippers do, or what you want:

```
comment_line  = qi::lit('*') >> *(qi::graph) >> qi::space >> *(qi::graph) >> qi::space >> qi::graph;
```

I'd expect a simple syntax like:

```
comment_line  = '*' >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol);
```

### Suggested Fix

I'd suggest to make comment just another statement, like they appear in the example. Don't make the string optional, because you can never have a comment line without a string. A line with a single `*` will be an empty string:

```
namespace Ast {
    using boost::optional;
    using Comment = std::string;

    struct Element {
        optional<std::string> label, node1, node2;
        optional<double>      value;
    };
    using Statement  = boost::variant<Comment, Element>;
    using Statements = std::vector<Statement>;

    struct SpiceNetlist {
        Statements statements;
    };
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::SpiceNetlist, statements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Element, label, node1, node2, value)
```

Now you can adjust the grammar likewise:

```
    spice_netlist_ = qi::skip(qi::blank)[statements_];

    statements_ = statement_ % qi::eol;
    statement_  = comment_ | element_;
    comment_    = qi::char_('*') >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol);
    element_    = -label_ >> -node1_ >> -node2_ >> -value_;
    label_      = +qi::graph;
    node1_      = +qi::graph;
    node2_      = +qi::graph;
    value_      = qi::double_;
```

Now, already the output is close:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e1382f104443816)**

```
Parsing: "* comment line 1
V1 N001 N002 10
R1 N001 N002 24.9

*comment line 2
R2 N002 N003 20
V2 N002 N003 5

* some
* more comment lines without particular layout
" -> Parse SUCCESS
Remaining: ""
* comment line 1
Element Label: V1 Node1: N001 Node2: N002 Value: 10
Element Label: R1 Node1: N001 Node2: N002 Value: 24.9
Element Label:-- Node1:-- Node2:-- Value:--
*comment line 2
Element Label: R2 Node1: N002 Node2: N003 Value: 20
Element Label: V2 Node1: N002 Node2: N003 Value: 5
Element Label:-- Node1:-- Node2:-- Value:--
* some
* more comment lines without particular layout
Element Label:-- Node1:-- Node2:-- Value:--
```

> Note that for no particular reason I chose to include the `*` inside the comment string, so the output looks more readable

### The Empty Trailing Element

This is caused by `element_` having only optional parts. `q = -a >> -b >> -c >> -d` will always match a zero-length input, so `*q` will infinitely match and `q % eol` will match empty lines too. Fix that by making at least one part non-optional:

```
element_    = label_ >> -node1_ >> -node2_ >> -value_;
```

What you probably expect is that empty lines have *no* effect:

```
statements_ = -statement_ % qi::eol;
```

### Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93fa3572bbf3a2fc)**

```cpp
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace Ast {
    using boost::optional;
    using Comment = std::string;

    struct Element {
        optional<std::string> label, node1, node2;
        optional<double>      value;
    };
    using Statement  = boost::variant<Comment, Element>;
    using Statements = std::vector<Statement>;

    struct SpiceNetlist {
        Statements statements;
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::Element const& el) {
        return os << "Element Label:" << el.label << " Node1:" << el.node1 << " Node2:" << el.node2
                  << " Value:" << el.value;
    }
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::SpiceNetlist, statements)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Element, label, node1, node2, value)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It> //
struct SpiceGrammar : qi::grammar<It, Ast::SpiceNetlist()> {
    SpiceGrammar() : SpiceGrammar::base_type(spice_netlist_) {
        spice_netlist_ = qi::skip(qi::blank)[statements_];

        statements_ = -statement_ % qi::eol;
        statement_  = comment_ | element_;
        comment_    = qi::char_('*') >> *(qi::char_ - qi::eol);
        element_    = label_ >> -node1_ >> -node2_ >> -value_;
        label_      = +qi::graph;
        node1_      = +qi::graph;
        node2_      = +qi::graph;
        value_      = qi::double_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES( //
            (spice_netlist_)(element_)(comment_)(statements_)(statement_)(label_)(node1_)(node2_)(value_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Ast::SpiceNetlist()> spice_netlist_;
    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;

    qi::rule<It, Ast::Statements(), Skipper> statements_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Element(), Skipper>    element_;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Statement(), Skipper>  statement_;

    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Comment()> comment_;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>  label_, node1_, node2_;
    qi::rule<It, double()>       value_;
};

Ast::SpiceNetlist parse_netlist_from_string(std::string_view input) {
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    static SpiceGrammar<It> const g;

    Ast::SpiceNetlist netlist;

    It   f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    bool success = qi::parse(f, l, g, netlist);

    std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted(input) << " -> "
              << "Parse " << (success ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED") << "\n"
              << "Remaining: " << quoted(std::string_view(f, l)) << std::endl;

    return netlist;
}

int main() {
    auto netlist = parse_netlist_from_string(R"(* comment line 1
V1 N001 N002 10
R1 N001 N002 24.9

*comment line 2
R2 N002 N003 20
V2 N002 N003 5

* some
* more comment lines without particular layout
)");
    for (auto const& stmt : netlist.statements) {
        std::cout << stmt << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
Parsing: "* comment line 1
V1 N001 N002 10
R1 N001 N002 24.9

*comment line 2
R2 N002 N003 20
V2 N002 N003 5

* some
* more comment lines without particular layout
" -> Parse SUCCESS
Remaining: ""
* comment line 1
Element Label: V1 Node1: N001 Node2: N002 Value: 10
Element Label: R1 Node1: N001 Node2: N002 Value: 24.9
*comment line 2
Element Label: R2 Node1: N002 Node2: N003 Value: 20
Element Label: V2 Node1: N002 Node2: N003 Value: 5
* some
* more comment lines without particular layout
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much

Comment: To alternative put the comments with a particular element: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/930e3217cf5ae7b5 note this seems the wrong approach to me, both because comments don't seem to apply to a single element, and also because it cannot deal with comments appearing elsewhere, like at the end